# UPDATE query DateTime overflow

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I use SQL Server 2012 and VS 2012. I have a table with following data:

```
TagID      SessionID       ScanningTime
 int       nvarchar          datetime
---------------------------------------
4820427      Test1    2013-08-16 14:20:17.447
```

I have created an UPDATE query to save any changes that been made (any records added or existing records edited) in DGV back to SQL DB.

So for example I will add a new record and edit the existing one to look like this:

```
TagID      SessionID       ScanningTime
 int       nvarchar          datetime
---------------------------------------
4820000     Test1     2013-08-16 14:20:17.447
3242341     Test1     2013-08-16 14:20:17.447
```

And click the button to update the database:

```
private void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable queryResult = new DataTable();
            foreach (DataGridViewRow  row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int tagID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["TagID"].Value);
                string sessionID = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["SessionID"].Value);
                DateTime ScanningTime = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells["ScanningTime"].Value);

            string ConnStr = "Data Source=DUZY;Initial Catalog=AutoRegSQL;Integrated Security=True";

            SqlConnection MyConn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr);
            MyConn.Open();

            //SQL query that returns todays sessions for the given roomID
            string query = @"UPDATE Attendance" +
               " SET TagID= @tagNo, SessionID= @sessionNo, ScanningTime= @scantime ";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, MyConn);

            command.Parameters.Add("tagNo", SqlDbType.Int).Value =  tagID;
            command.Parameters.Add("sessionNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sessionID;
            command.Parameters.Add("scantime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ScanningTime;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);


            adapter.Fill(queryResult);


            MyConn.Close();

            }
        }
```

When I click the button to save the changes i receive an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
```

**EDIT**:

Looking back to my SSMS, the content of Attendance table has changed after trying to update the table. The original record was replaced by the record that was added manualy (despite the error).

Attendance table after UPDATE query execution:

```
    TagID      SessionID       ScanningTime
     int       nvarchar          datetime
    ---------------------------------------
    5453453     Test1   2013-08-16 14:20:00.000
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is all of your code? The query lacks of a where clause, so it updates all records in your table, the query is an UPDATE query so it doesn't return anything but the number of rows affected. Finally the Fill inside the loop doesn't make sense

Comment: I don't know where in the world you are but just sanity check that your cultures are correct.  In the UK we get this a lot when we're trying to insert a day into a US culture month column!

Comment: you need to check what the`DataType` of the `ScanningTime` field is. your problem seems to be an obvious `Format DateTime` Issue. also I would change the `Parameters.Add` to `Parameters.AddWithValue` let the Server figure out the DataType.

Comment: I'm based in UK. ScanningTime data type is datetime. How do I check the cultures? Why -1?

Comment: @jaspernorth - At this stage, your next step should be to spin up SQL Profiler and watch the query go to the database to see what is actually being passed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that the SQL Server is making an assumption about the format of the date that is incorrect in this case.

Try converting your DateTime like this when you add it to your parameters:

```
ScanningTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to format datetime like universal literal in SQL, that is `YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss[.mmm]`, because this format is culture independent

Or, you can try even this:

```
string myDatetime = ScanningTime .ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff");
```

And in UPDATE statement pass new variable `myDateTime`‚.

One thing that you need to check first, is whether ScanningTime is maybe NULL, because, datetime field in SQL table expect some value, and for datetime data type, minimum value is `1/1/1753 12:00:00` and maximum value is `12/31/9999 11:59:59`.

Comment: I have tried, but the same error occurs
string format = "YYYYMMDD hh:mm:ss[.mmm]";
                ScanningTime.ToString(format);

Comment: Can you debug your code at point where you assign value to UPDATE statement, to see in which format datetime is sent to SQL?

Comment: Check. System.DateTime

Comment: Still the same result, and ScanningTime has a value of "2013/08/16 14:20:00"

Comment: Can you post output of debug process, to see what is happening